# IDE Plugin to disable the Insert key

Tags: delphi, plugins

I've been playing around with an IDE plugin for Delphi (10.3 Rio) to disable the insert key (does anyone actually use type-over mode?).

It installs into the IDE fine, but if I uninstall it, an exception occurs when I press the insert key.

Can anyone help me out here?

Here is the updated source:
(I've added the finalization section, still get an error)

```
unit MyBinding;

interface

procedure Register;

implementation

uses Windows, Classes, SysUtils, ToolsAPI, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TLearnDelphiKeyBinding = class(TNotifierObject, IOTAKeyboardBinding)
  private
    procedure DoNothing(const Context: IOTAKeyContext; KeyCode: TShortCut; var BindingResult: TKeyBindingResult);

  public
    function GetBindingType: TBindingType;
    function GetDisplayName: string;
    function GetName: string;
    procedure BindKeyboard(const BindingServices: IOTAKeyBindingServices);
  end;

var
  LearnDelphiKeyBindingIndex : integer = 0;

procedure Register;
begin
  LearnDelphiKeyBindingIndex := (BorlandIDEServices as IOTAKeyBoardServices).AddKeyboardBinding(TLearnDelphiKeyBinding.Create);
end;

procedure TLearnDelphiKeyBinding.BindKeyboard(const BindingServices: IOTAKeyBindingServices);
begin
  BindingServices.AddKeyBinding([ShortCut(VK_INSERT, [])], DoNothing, nil);
end;

function TLearnDelphiKeyBinding.GetBindingType: TBindingType;
begin
  Result := btPartial;
end;

function TLearnDelphiKeyBinding.GetDisplayName: string;
begin
  Result := 'Disable Insert';
end;

function TLearnDelphiKeyBinding.GetName: string;
begin
  Result := 'LearnDelphi.DisableInsert';
end;

procedure TLearnDelphiKeyBinding.DoNothing(const Context: IOTAKeyContext;
  KeyCode: TShortCut; var BindingResult: TKeyBindingResult);
begin
  BindingResult := krHandled;
end;

initialization
finalization
  if LearnDelphiKeyBindingIndex > 0 then
    (BorlandIDEServices as IOTAKeyboardServices).RemoveKeyboardBinding(LearnDelphiKeyBindingIndex);

end.
```

[image]

Comment: "does anyone actually use type-over mode?" I use it many times daily. Here's a practical example (a bit down, under its own section): https://rejbrand.se/rejbrand/article.asp?ItemIndex=479

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Not exactly a compelling example, but I'll keep it in mind - maybe I'll remember to use it one day - assuming that I haven't disabled the Insert key.

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `IOTAKeyboardServices.RemoveKeyboardBinding()` during `finalization`, passing it the value returned by `IOTAKeyboardServices.AddKeyboardBinding()` (which you are not currently saving).

Have a look at [Chapter 4: Key Bindings and Debugging Tools](http://www.davidghoyle.co.uk/WordPress/?p=236) in David Hoyle's blog, which provides an example of a keyboard binding wizard using the OpenTools API.

Comment: I still get an access violation when pressing Insert after disabling the package, not sure what is going wrong here.  I've updated the source code in the question